# How can I override a java class function using Jpype?

Tags: java, python, jpype

I am studying python and I am using python 3.5 with the Jpype module.

The issue I am running into is that I want to override a function that was made in Java from python.

**My Java Code:**

```
package test;

public class TestApi
{
    public void processMessage() {}
}
```

I compiled the java code to the jar file, TestApi.jar, and then I used the Jpype module in python in order to load it the class in my python script.

**Here is my python code:**

```
from jpype import *

jvmpath = getDefaultJVMPath()
startJVM(jvmpath, "-ea", ("-Djava.class.path=TestApi.jar"))
TestApiClass = JClass("test.TestApi") #i can read java class
javaApi = TestApiClass()

def PythonApi():
   print("hello world")
```

With this code I would like to override the `proccessMessage` function from the class in Java using the `PythonAPI` function in my python code. Is this possible? and if it is how can this be done?